# Assigned Offset is not availble with Kafka Cosnumer (Offset out of Range)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am consuming from a Kafka topic with Assign Offset

`KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(sparkStreamingContext, PreferConsistent, Assign[String, String](fromOffsets.keys, kafkaConsumerParams, fromOffsets))`

We have Kafka consumer messages **retention period as 4 days**.

Suppose If I try to consume message from topic which already expired because of retention. Its **throwing offset out of range exception**.

So I want to check whether the assigning offset is present or not in consumer topic. If not present I'll make auto.offset.reset as earliest.

Please any one give Suggestion. **How do I check assigning offset is present or not** in Kafka.

Comment: You can use GetOffsetShell or plain KafkaConsumer class to query topic offsets

Comment: Any way to do this with Scala code ?